# Is $\langle \nabla \omega, \eta \rangle \mathrm{dVol}_g=\nabla \omega \wedge \star \eta$ meaningful? How?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I know that  $ \omega\wedge \star \eta=\langle \omega, \eta \rangle\mathrm{dVol}_g$. I want to know

> **Q1:** why the following make sense? $$\langle \nabla \omega, \eta \rangle  \mathrm{dVol}_g=\nabla \omega \wedge \star \eta,\qquad\omega,\eta\in\Omega^k(M).$$

I am asking this because $\nabla \omega$ is not a differential form in general. It is a $(0,k+1)$-tensor that has been wedge producted with a $(n-k)$-form $\star\eta$.

> **Q2:** I know that $\langle \nabla \omega, \eta \rangle$ is a $(0,1)$-tensor, so **what is the product between thatand $\mathrm{dVol}_g$ in the above displayed relation?**

Also

> **Q3:** Does  $\star\nabla\omega$  make sense? i.e. Hodge star acting on tensors!! (because in general $\star\nabla=\nabla\star$ then it must make sense I think but how it works in practice?)

p.s. [Motivating MO post.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/97095/90655)

Comment: It's best to think of $\nabla \omega$ as a 1-form-valued $k$-form and therefore, $\nabla\omega\wedge \star\eta$ as a covector-valued $n$-form. In other words, given $k$ tangent vectors $v_1, \dots, v_k$, $\nabla\omega(v_1, \dots, v_k)$ is the $1$-form $v \mapsto \nabla\omega(v,v_1,\dots, v_m)$.

Comment: So $\langle \nabla \omega, \eta \rangle  \mathrm{dVol}_g$ is $\langle \nabla \omega, \eta \rangle\otimes  \mathrm{dVol}_g$?

Comment: Yes. You can work this out with respect to a local orthonormal frame