# "Covariant" hodge star operator

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, gauge-theory

I've some question about not(at)ions i've found on this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0403048.pdf

Let $(M,g)$ be a $n$-dimensional ortientable compact riemannian manifold with boundary $\Gamma$.

- A "gauge field $A$ defined in a Hermitian vector bundle $E$ over $M$ of rank $N$" (page 3, beginning of the section 2) is just a connection on the vector bundle?
- If the answer to the previous question is positive, $d_A\colon C^{\infty}(M,E)\to \Omega^1(M,E)$ (end of page 3) acts like the connection $A$?
- If the answer to the previous question is positive, how can i consider $\star d_A\psi$ (eq (2.5)), where $\star$ is the Hodge star operator of $M$ and $\psi\in C^\infty(M,E)$.

I'm a bit confused because the Hodge star operator works with $p$-forms of $M$ and not $E$-valued $p$-forms (i.e. elements of $\Omega^p(M,E)$).

Is there a generalization of this operator that I ignore?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hodge star is an isomorphism between k-forms and (n-k)-forms. for example in 2d dimension it sends $dx$ to $dy$ and $1$ to $dx\wedge dy$. in summary: $\star \omega\wedge \omega=dVol_g$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this valid also for $E$-valued forms?

Comment: @C.F.G More like $\star \omega \wedge \omega = \|\omega\|^2 dVol_g$ right?

Comment: @Didier: Ah, You are absolutely right.

Comment: @MarcoPacelli: Take a look to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4071031/272127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, gauge fields are essentially physics terminology (probably originating from electrodynamics) for connections in some bundle of interest (here a vector bundle over $M$).

Next, note that $C^{\infty}(M,E)$ typically denotes all smooth maps from $M$ into $E$, so I find it odd that the paper uses it to denote the space of sections. If we wish to speak of only the smooth sections, the correct notation is something like $\Gamma(E)$ or $\Omega^0(M,E)$ ($E$-valued $0$-forms on $M$). The object $d_{A}$ is known as the [exterior covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_covariant_derivative#For_vector_bundles) (which is typically denoted as $d_{\nabla}$ or $d^{\nabla}$). Also, yes, for a smooth section $\psi\in \Omega^0(M,E)$, we define $d_{\nabla}\psi:= \nabla\psi$. The reason it becomes an $E$-valued $1$-form on $M$ is because $\nabla_{(\cdot)}\psi$ has a slot which can be
filled in by an element of $TM$, and if you feed it a $\xi_x\in T_xM$ then the output is $\nabla_{\xi_x}\psi\in E_x$.

Finally, regarding Hodge stars, let us first consider the case of vector spaces; we can then generalize to vector bundles by doing things fiber-by-fiber. Let $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be an $n$-dimensional oriented pseudo-inner product space
and let $E$ be a vector space. Note that an $E$-valued $k$-form on $V$ can be defined in several equivalent ways:

- an alternating multiliner map $\underbrace{V\times\cdots \times V}_{\text{$k$ times}}\to E$
- a linear map $\bigwedge^k(V)\to E$
- an element of $\left(\bigwedge^k(V)\right)^*\otimes E\cong \left(\bigwedge^k(V^*)\right)\otimes E$

We shall use the third description. Let $\star:\bigwedge^k(V^*)\to \bigwedge^{n-k}(V^*)$ be the usual Hodge-star defined by the orientation and pseudo-inner product of $V$. This allows us to consider a bilinear map $\bigwedge^k(V^*)\times E\to \bigwedge^{n-k}(V^*)\otimes E$ defined as $(\alpha,\xi)\mapsto (\star\alpha)\otimes \xi$. Since this is a bilinear map, the universal property of tensor products tells us that we get a corresponding linear map $\star_E:\bigwedge^k(V^*)\otimes E\to \bigwedge^{n-k}(V^*)\otimes E$ such that for all "pure tensors" $\alpha\otimes \xi\in \bigwedge^{k}(V^*)\otimes E$, we have
\begin{align}
\star_E(\alpha\otimes \xi)&=(\star \alpha)\otimes \xi.
\end{align}
Hence, $\star_E$ is the desired mapping. It takes $E$-valued $k$-forms on $V$ to $E$-valued $(n-k)$-forms on $V$, and this definition is such that in the special case $E=\Bbb{R}$ is the underlying field, it coincides with the usual definition of $\star$ (after identifying a vector space of the form $W\otimes \Bbb{R}$ with $W$ in the natural way).

Now that we know how Hodge-star works at the level of vector spaces, you can do it at the vector-bundle level by doing things fiber-by-fiber to get a vector bundle morphism $\star_E:\bigwedge^k(T^*M)\otimes E\to \bigwedge^{n-k}(T^*M)\otimes E$, and hence by applying this to forms pointwise, we obtain a mapping $\Omega^k(M,E)\to \Omega^{n-k}(M,E)$ for each value of $k$. In particular, if $\psi$ is a smooth section, then $d_{\nabla}\psi$ is an $E$-valued 1-form on $M$, so its Hodge star is an $E$-valued $(n-1)$-form on $M$.

Comment: Although I agree with you that this can be confusing, there are several references where the space of sections of a vector bundle $\pi\colon E\to M$ is denoted $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M;E)$.

Comment: @Didier thank you fro the comment, I actually didn't know that. When I briefly glossed over the paper, I was initially confused, but then realized each time the authors said explicitly in words they're referring only to sections. However, since OP said "I have some questions about notation", I thought I might as well point this out in case they see it elsewhere.

Comment: Can i ask you another question? In the formula (2.5) the authors write "$(\star d_A \psi_1,\psi_2) $".  I think they mean the $n-1$ form that at each $x\in M$ assigns the map $(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1})\mapsto ((\star d_A \psi_1)_x(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}),,\psi_2(x))_x\in \mathbb C$ (i'm viewing $E$-valued forms as alterning maps). Is that true?

Comment: @MarcoPacelli that sounds right (I'm assuming you mean $X_i\in T_xM$). This is now a usual $(n-1)$-form on $M$ of which we're taking the usual exterior derivative and integrating over $M$. Hence, by Stokes, it is the "boundary term".

Comment: You assume well! Thank you a lot for your help. I've some other little doubts but maybe I'll post them in a new thread.